# product of two Lebesgue spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that if $f\in L_p(R), g\in L_q(R)$. Then $h=fg \in L_s(R)$ ($1/p+1/q=1/s$). I've said that $|h|^s = |h|^{pq/(p+q)}$. I then define $f=h|h|^{p/(p+q)-1}$ and $g=|h|^{q/(p+q)}$. Then it's trivial that $fg\in L_s(R)$. But why are $f,g$ in $L_p, L_q$ respectively?

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are given to you. Why are trying to define $f$ and $g$?

Comment: see if my revised answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a mistype when you said $fg \in L_p$. It should be $fg \in L_s$. If $f\in L_p$ and $g \in L_q$ then $\int |fg|^{s} \leq (\int |f|^{p})^{s/p} (\int |g|^{q})^{s/q}$ by Holder's inequality (because $\frac s p +\frac s q=1$). Hence $\int |fg|^{s} <\infty$.

Wait, let me guess. You have made of mess of things but I think what you really want is a proof of the fact that $h \in L_s$ implies there exist $f\in L_p, g\in L_q$ such that $h=fg$. For this define $f=h|h|^{s/p-1}$ and $g=|h|^{s/q}$. Then $fg=h|h|^{s(\frac 1 p+\frac 1 q -1)}=h$ and it is obvious that $f\in L_p$ and $ g\in L_q$.